# Write an independent job which has no impact to the current system in .net core API

Tags: c#, .net, api, .net-core

I'm working on a CRM application and my client wants to download some information within last 6 months. At the moment I have created an API endpoint which returns `FileContentResult` object and that will open a new tab in browser and automatically download an Excel file.

But this process is time consuming (since it has over 500K data) and users don't wait in the same page until the process is done. So, once an user change between pages I get issues and sometimes the application return timeout error since the API response is slow.

Now, I'm planning to enhance that same function/API endpoint by introducing some silent job. Which means once user click on "Download" button, process will start and it will send a message stating that "Your download process has been started. You will receive an email with the report within next 15minutes". In this way, users don't have to wait and they can do something else in the system.

Currently, I'm using async task and awaits until the job is done.

```
        public async Task<FileContentResult> ExportData()
        {
            //...
            //... process data and create excel file
            //...
            //...
            return new FileContentResult(*some byte array*, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
            {
                FileDownloadName = $"Data.xlsx"
            };
        }
```

and I'm calling this method by

```
await exportService.ExportData();
```

My concern is what are the things I should change here in order to avoid any impact on other processes and run this as a background job. Once I get the result, I will send an email with an attachment.

Please help me with your valuable ideas. Thanks in advance

Comment: If the issue consists of fetching all 500k records at the same time, and then taking the time to process them, you could look into creating a paginated approach to fetching them, that way you can fetch a bit, work on them while you process the next fetch request etc.

Comment: Yes, Im doing pagination here (around 250 pages). So there is a loop in the process. Even I added a parallel foreach once which caused some other issue by mixing data. Anyway,I have several db calls and that makes the process slow. Is there a way that we can run this process as a background job using a thread or something? So once its done, I can send an email.

Comment: If you haven't already, take a look at projects like [hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/), I think that would solve your problem of scheduling jobs, and it also makes sure you can continue jobs with code afterwards as if you were doing task continuation, and handles the storage part for you, if you want to run jobs in the future

Comment: As a sidenote, you can always just make a task, run it, and not await the result, as long as the method is sort of self contained, or at least has references to non garbage collected services, you should be fine doing that, although it's not as pretty as running scheduled background jobs.
eg. just don't await the call to `ExportData()`, and then add a `ContinueWith()` to the end of it, that way you can send the email once it's done processing, without having the user wait, and without needing to create your own background job flow, but again, not the prettiest solution, but easy :)

Answer (score 1):

> what are the things I should change here in order to avoid any impact on other processes and run this as a background job. Once I get the result, I will send an email with an attachment.

You should use a [basic distributed architecture](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2021/01/asynchronous-messaging-1-basic-distributed-architecture.html), as I describe on my blog. Specifically:

1. Instead of creating the report in your ASP.NET app, your ASP.NET app should just create a message indicating that the report should be created, and place that message into a durable queue.
2. Have a separate, independent process read the messages from that queue, generate the report, and send the email.